# How to Carry forward a column value while inserting other column values in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a scenario. Say I have a table named "log" and it looks as below:

```
id | timestamp | batchid     | data |
====================================
1  |  time1    |   1     | 1000 |    
2  |  time2    |   1     | 1015 |    
3  |  time3    |   1     | 1018 |    
4  |  time4    |   1     | 1025 |
```

.
and so on...

id is set as an auto incrementing. Timestamp and data is inserted periodically via standard mysql insert query. 
Now batchid can be specified by user. 
Now what I want is to carry forward batchid data while it's inserting other column data periodically. If user changes batchid , I will use mysql UPDATE query to change its data in last row and hence then it will carry forward that batch id from then on.

For example...

Currently my table looks like

```
id | timestamp | batchid     | data |
====================================
1  |  time1    |   1     | 1000 |    
2  |  time2    |   1     | 1015 |    
3  |  time3    |   1     | 1018 |    
4  |  time4    |   1     | 1025 |
```

Now a user event to change the batch id = 3 and hence it would look like...

```
id | timestamp | batchid     | data |
====================================
1  |  time1    |   1     | 1000 |    
2  |  time2    |   1     | 1015 |    
3  |  time3    |   1     | 1018 |    
4  |  time4    |   3     | 1025 |
```

and then periodic inserts keeps following...

```
id | timestamp | batchid     | data |
====================================
1  |  time1    |   1     | 1000 |    
2  |  time2    |   1     | 1015 |    
3  |  time3    |   1     | 1018 |    
4  |  time4    |   3     | 1025 |    
5  |  time5    |   3     | 1026 |    
6  |  time6    |   3     | 1028 |
```

carrying forward batchid column with it.

Any ideas ? Do I need to set any field options while creating a mysql table or something ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this should get the last batchid ----  SELECT batchid
FROM log
WHERE timestamp >= (
   SELECT DATE(MAX(timestamp))
   FROM log
); ---

Comment: I agree. Even "SELECT batchid FROM log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;" will do. And then I can use batchid while inserting. But I was wondering if there's a way to retain previous value ? For example...auto incrementing. You can always have last value via this sorta queries and then add 1 and then insert. Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO my_table 
SELECT NULL
     , 'time5'
     , x.batchid
     , 1026 FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id > x.id -- or y.timestamp > x.timestamp if that's more appropriate
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```